# Flash messages in Rails 3.2.3 and json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, ruby-on-rails-3.2

There is an action in a controller. It can be called only **with json format via ajax**.

```
def update
    @article = Article.find_by_id params[:id]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.update_attributes(params[:article])
        flash[:message] = "good"       
      else
        flash[:error] = @article.errors.full_messages.join(", ")
      end
          format.json { render :json => flash}
  end

end
```

the part of a page

```
<% unless flash[:error].blank? %>
   <%= flash[:error] %>
<% end %>

<% unless flash[:message].blank? %>
  <%= flash[:notice] %>
<% end %>
<!-- page content goes -->
```

Of course, a page contains a `button_to` with `:remote=>true` that calls the method `update`.

The bottom line is that it shows nothing after updating. JSON object definitely returns, I can see it in fireBug.

The question is, am I using flash correctly? And how do I use it to show a message on a page? Please don't forget about ajax.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think 
You have to bind `ajax:success` call back which will display flash message by replacing message or placing message to dom.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you have an if/else statement in your respond_to block?

```
def update
  @article = Article.find_by_id params[:id]
  if @article.update_attributes(params[:article])
    flash[:notice] = "Good"
  else
    flash.now[:notice] = "Bad"
    render "edit"
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to @article}
    format.js
  end
end
```

Then create **update.js.erb**

```
$("#notice").text("<%= escape_javascript(flash[:notice]) %>")
$("#notice").show()
```

Code above might not be 100% correct.

For flash, I'd have something like:

```
<div id="notice">
  <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <%= content_tag(:div, value, :class => "flash #{key}") %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: I asked, how do I display flash message for json object? You answer about js.

Comment: Totally confused. If you are submitting a request by Ajax, it responds to `format.js` not `format.json`, that's just for a json request.

Comment: As I said, I need to handle a json request.

Answer (score 1):

This posting has all the code you'll need. It saved my hide:

https://gist.github.com/linjunpop/3410235

Here's a fork of it that makes a few minor modifications:

https://gist.github.com/timothythehuman/5506787